# Canvas Js Write Different Value On Each Bar C# Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, canvasjs

How can I write different values inside and outside of each bar ?

**Sample Data**

for single bar is something like

> X=21538, Y=25666 , Name = 'July'

Now the graph should render like this

**Expected**

[image]

**Current**

[image]

**Class**

```
   public class DataPoint
 {
    public DataPoint(string label, double y)
    {
        this.Label = label;
        this.Y = y;
     
       // this.X = x;
    }

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "label")]
    public string Label = "";




    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "y")]
    public Nullable<double> Y = null;


}
```

Also when I try to use x as another point the graph shows abnormal result.
Please help.

Comment: It's totally unclear how you are trying to render the graphs

Comment: The graph you expect, I have never seen that before so I doubt a library maker would take that into account. In other words, canvasjs won't be able to do this. Do you know the name of such graph?

Comment: actually this chart was generated on excel.

Comment: please show the code you are using so far to create the chart

Comment: P.S. https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/ appears to show all the possible chart types. Not sure the library can exactly reproduce what you want. Maybe consider displaying the information a slightly different way, but conveying the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem I found is.

```
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
title: {
    text: '@(Model.topTitleChart)'
},
axisY: {
    title:  '@(Model.leftTitleChart)'
},

data: [{
    type: "column",
    indexLabel: "{innerValue}",
    indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
    dataPoints: @Html.Raw(Model.dataPoints)
}]
        });
addIndexLabel();
chart.render();
function addIndexLabel() {
    chart.options.data.push({ type: "scatter", color: "transparent", toolTipContent: null, dataPoints: [] });
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.length; i++)
        chart.options.data[1].dataPoints.push({ x: chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[i].x, y: chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[i].y, indexLabel: chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[i].outerValue });
}
```

**Class**

```
  [DataContract]
   public class DataPoint
   {
      public DataPoint(string x, double y,string innerval,string outerval)
      {
        this.label = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.innerValue = innerval;
        this.outerValue = outerval;


       // this.X = x;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "label")]
    public string label { get; set; }

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "y")]
    public Nullable<double> y = null;

    [DataMember(Name = "outerValue")]
    public string outerValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "innerValue")]
    public string innerValue { get; set; }


}
```

**Result**
[image]